# Issue with Rails Generator Building a Plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am building a Rails plugin for an application at work.

I want to extract logic that was used in multiple locations, but implemented slightly differently, and add new features needed without doing it 2-3 times over.

I've never build a gem, but according to what I was reading it is possible to use `rails generate`.

However this has not been the case for me.

Running `rails g model Something stuff:type`:[image]

First interesting thing is that it is generating mini test stuff when I explicitly told the plugin not to use mini test (using Rspec).

Then looking in my folder structure for the plugin, no `db/` folder, nothing added to `app/models/`, and no `test/` folder:

[image]

Running the command a second time reveals to me that the files are indeed created:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Where is this stuff going? Can I even find out?
2. Has anyone encountered something similar? Is it due to a misconfiguration, or bug? Essentially, what's happening?

I would truly appreciate any advice or suggestions!

#### EDIT #1

Forgot to mention that I checked within the `spec/dummy` application in case things were being created there, and it is still empty as I left it.

[image]

#### EDIT #2

So I found where the files were by using the `find` command:

[image]

And yeah it added the files to my home folder...

At least now I can just paste them in the right location, but obviously this is bizarre and I'd like to get this resolved, figure out what is going on.

Comment: Are you creating your gem as `Railtie` or an `Engine`?

Comment: See my answer below. Generate and look for your models in `spec/dummy` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so turns out that **yes** you may use Rails Generators when building a gem. Also, the generated files **will not** be placed inside the dummy application unless you are in that directory.

Everything is working as expected on a different computer.

Answer (score -1):

1. That stuff is going into dummy app that is usually located in `test/dummy`. In your case, it seems to be located in `specs/dummy`.
2. Yeap and nope. That's not misconfiguration.

Comment: What is happening and how you came to this conclusion?